# Mountain Lion VPN fails to connect but works on Windows VM

Tags: macos, vpn

I want to setup a VPN on my mac but I can't make it work. If I start my Windows 7 VM, the VPN connects fine (from Windows) but if I try to connect from my Mac it fails…

First of all, here is the system log:

```
Oct  7 15:18:45 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local configd[18]: SCNC: start, triggered by System Preferen, type L2TP, status 0  
Oct  7 15:18:45 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local pppd[3385]: pppd 2.4.2 (Apple version 596.15.2) started by leo, uid 501  
Oct  7 15:18:45 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local pppd[3385]: L2TP connecting to server 'vpn.aec.com.br' (186.249.4.10)...  
Oct  7 15:18:45 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local pppd[3385]: IPSec connection started  
Oct  7 15:18:46 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local racoon[192]: Connecting.  
Oct  7 15:18:46 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local racoon[192]: IPSec Phase1 started (Initiated by me).  
Oct  7 15:18:46 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local racoon[192]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Initiator, Aggressive-Mode message 1).  
Oct  7 15:18:47 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local com.apple.quicklook.satellite[3358]: [QL] No sandbox token for thumbnail request file://localhost/private/var/log/racoon.log, it will probably fail  
Oct  7 15:18:47 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(3386) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd  
Oct  7 15:18:48 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local sandboxd[3386] ([3358]): QuickLookSatelli(3358) deny file-read-data /private/var/log/racoon.log  
Oct  7 15:18:49 --- last message repeated 2 times ---  
Oct  7 15:18:49 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local racoon[192]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).  
Oct  7 15:18:50 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local com.apple.quicklook.satellite[3358]: [QL] No sandbox token for thumbnail request file://localhost/private/var/log/racoon.log, it will probably fail  
Oct  7 15:18:50 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local sandboxd[3386] ([3358]): QuickLookSatelli(3358) deny file-read-data /private/var/log/racoon.log  
Oct  7 15:18:51 --- last message repeated 2 times ---  
Oct  7 15:18:51 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local com.apple.quicklook.satellite[3358]: [QL] No sandbox token for thumbnail request file://localhost/private/var/log/racoon.log, it will probably fail  
Oct  7 15:18:52 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local sandboxd[3386] ([3358]): QuickLookSatelli(3358) deny file-read-data /private/var/log/racoon.log  
Oct  7 15:18:52 --- last message repeated 1 time ---  
Oct  7 15:18:52 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local racoon[192]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).  
Oct  7 15:18:52 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local sandboxd[3386] ([3358]): QuickLookSatelli(3358) deny file-read-data /private/var/log/racoon.log  
Oct  7 15:18:52 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local com.apple.quicklook.satellite[3358]: [QL] No sandbox token for thumbnail request file://localhost/private/var/log/racoon.log, it will probably fail  
Oct  7 15:18:53 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local sandboxd[3386] ([3358]): QuickLookSatelli(3358) deny file-read-data /private/var/log/racoon.log  
Oct  7 15:18:54 --- last message repeated 2 times ---  
Oct  7 15:18:54 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local com.apple.quicklook.satellite[3358]: [QL] No sandbox token for thumbnail request file://localhost/private/var/log/racoon.log, it will probably fail  
Oct  7 15:18:54 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local sandboxd[3386] ([3358]): QuickLookSatelli(3358) deny file-read-data /private/var/log/racoon.log  
Oct  7 15:18:55 --- last message repeated 2 times ---  
Oct  7 15:18:55 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local racoon[192]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).  
Oct  7 15:18:55 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local com.apple.quicklook.satellite[3358]: [QL] No sandbox token for thumbnail request file://localhost/private/var/log/racoon.log, it will probably fail  
Oct  7 15:18:56 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local pppd[3385]: IPSec connection failed  
Oct  7 15:18:56 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local pppd[3385]: L2TP connecting to alternate server 'vpn.aec.com.br' (200.251.240.177)...  
Oct  7 15:18:56 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local pppd[3385]: IPSec connection started  
Oct  7 15:18:56 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local racoon[192]: Connecting.  
Oct  7 15:18:56 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local racoon[192]: IPSec Phase1 started (Initiated by me).  
Oct  7 15:18:56 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local racoon[192]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Initiator, Aggressive-Mode message 1).  
Oct  7 15:18:56 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local sandboxd[3386] ([3358]): QuickLookSatelli(3358) deny file-read-data /private/var/log/racoon.log  
Oct  7 15:18:56 --- last message repeated 2 times ---  
Oct  7 15:18:56 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local com.apple.quicklook.satellite[3358]: [QL] No sandbox token for thumbnail request file://localhost/private/var/log/racoon.log, it will probably fail  
Oct  7 15:18:57 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local sandboxd[3386] ([3358]): QuickLookSatelli(3358) deny file-read-data /private/var/log/racoon.log  
Oct  7 15:18:59 --- last message repeated 2 times ---  
Oct  7 15:18:59 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local racoon[192]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).  
Oct  7 15:19:00 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local com.apple.quicklook.satellite[3358]: [QL] No sandbox token for thumbnail request file://localhost/private/var/log/racoon.log, it will probably fail  
Oct  7 15:19:00 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local sandboxd[3386] ([3358]): QuickLookSatelli(3358) deny file-read-data /private/var/log/racoon.log  
Oct  7 15:19:01 --- last message repeated 2 times ---  
Oct  7 15:19:01 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local com.apple.quicklook.satellite[3358]: [QL] No sandbox token for thumbnail request file://localhost/private/var/log/racoon.log, it will probably fail  
Oct  7 15:19:02 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local racoon[192]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).  
Oct  7 15:19:03 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local com.apple.quicklook.satellite[3358]: [QL] No sandbox token for thumbnail request file://localhost/private/var/log/racoon.log, it will probably fail  
Oct  7 15:19:03 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local sandboxd[3386] ([3358]): QuickLookSatelli(3358) deny file-read-data /private/var/log/racoon.log  
Oct  7 15:19:05 --- last message repeated 2 times ---  
Oct  7 15:19:05 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local com.apple.quicklook.satellite[3358]: [QL] No sandbox token for thumbnail request file://localhost/private/var/log/racoon.log, it will probably fail  
Oct  7 15:19:05 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local racoon[192]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).  
Oct  7 15:19:05 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local sandboxd[3386] ([3358]): QuickLookSatelli(3358) deny file-read-data /private/var/log/racoon.log  
Oct  7 15:19:06 --- last message repeated 2 times ---  
Oct  7 15:19:06 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local pppd[3385]: IPSec connection failed  
Oct  7 15:19:06 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local racoon[192]: IPSec disconnecting from server 200.251.240.177  
Oct  7 15:19:06 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local racoon[192]: IPSec disconnecting from server 186.249.4.10
```

Second: The Windows 7 VPN manual (the only one available) states that I should check the box "CHAP Protocol" & "CHAP v2" and I must select the option where encryption is required.

Third: I must also enter the pre-shared-key, which I deduce is the shared-secret option of mountain lion.

Still no luck at all… can anyone help?

**EDIT 1:** The dump file is [here](https://dashteststorage.blob.core.windows.net/generalimages/DumpFile01.pcap)

Comment: Are you using the built-in Windows VPN client to connect (i.e., did the instructions resemble those on this page:http://helpdesk.princeton.edu/kb/display.plx?ID=9987 ?)

Comment: @EddieKelley yes... looks a lot like that... I only have to set the shared key...

Comment: A packet capture of the traffic going between your machine and the VPN gateway may help us to diagnose the issues. You can use a Terminal command to capture that traffic into a file in your home directory named "dump.pcap": `sudo tcdump -w ~/dump.pcap host vpn.aec.com.br`. Start that command in Terminal, then attempt the VPN connection (and allow it to timeout). You can signal the `tcpdump` process with an interrupt (Control+C) to kill the packet trace. After the connection fails, you can post the capture file here for evaluation.

Comment: @EddieKelley ok! i edited the question... i dont know if i captured the right dump though... your command was invalid... so i used "sudo tcpdump -i en0 -s 0 -B 524288 -w ~/Desktop/DumpFile01.pcap"

Comment: My apologies - that should have been `sudo tcpdump -w ~/dump.pcap host vpn.aec.com.br`...The dump you performed definitely worked, but isn't providing any additional information. The packet trace shows your machine initiating and retrying the Phase 1 IPSec connection several times for each of the hosts, but is not receiving any response from the machines on the other side.

Answer (score 2):

It seems odd that your machine is attempting to use aggressive-mode in phase 1 of the IPSec connection. From what I can see, the default in 10.8.5 is to use main-mode. I'm wondering if you've modified the file at `/etc/racoon/racoon.conf` in trying to get this working? Can you post the contents of the file at `/etc/racoon/racoon.conf`?

Alternately, it may be possible to duplicate the configuration file that the L2TP/IPSec connection in System Preferences is using, and modify it slightly (configure to use main-mode) to see if that helps. Unfortunately, that configuration file is created at connect time, and is copied into /var/run/racoon/fqdn.of.host.conf. This file is also readable only by root (to protect the PSK that's stored inside of it). If you're quick, you can prepare a Terminal command that will copy that config file, initiate the VPN connection from System Preferences or the menu bar, and perform the copy command *while the VPN is attempting to connect* (you may have 5-10 seconds to perform the copy). Here's the command that you'd run right after initiating the VPN connection:

```
sudo cp -Rp /var/run/racoon/vpn.aec.com.br ~/Desktop
```

That file has permissions that disallow users from reading it. Use the command to make it readable:

```
sudo chmod 777 ~/Desktop/vpn.aec.com.br
```

***NOTE: the file that you've copied onto the Desktop contains your PSK. You should not post this file (unmodified) to this website. If you would like to post this configuration file for troubleshooting, obfuscate the value of `shared_secret` before posting.***

You can configure the VPN connection to use main-mode by modifying the configuration file that you've copied onto your Desktop. Open that file in any text editor, and locate the line that says `exchange_mode`. You may find that it says something like:

```
exchange_mode aggressive;
```

If so, see if you can change it so that it uses main-mode:

```
exchange_mode main;
```

Next, disable the built-in launchd script that launches `racoon` normally:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.racoon.plist
```

Then, you can temporarily launch `racoon`, and instruct it to use the configuration file that you exported:

```
sudo racoon -f ~/Desktop/vpn.aec.com.br -l /var/log/racoon.log
```

The racoon process will run in the background using the configuration file that you copied onto the Desktop. The process will also output to `/var/log/racoon.log` Next, you can initiate a VPN connection using racoonctl:

```
sudo racoonctl vpn-connect vpn.aec.com.br
```

The VPN menubar item will not update while this process is connecting. However, you should see output in `/var/log/system.log` and in `/var/log/racoon.log` that reflects the fact that the IPSec Phase 1 connection is moving along (i.e., Main Mode Message 2, 3, 4, etc.). If you see that the machine is able to establish the IPSec tunnel (look for "IPSec Phase1 established" in `system.log`), you're likely having problems with the exchange_mode that's configured.

**How to undo this configuration**

To put things back to the way that they were, you can disconnect (if the connection was successful) and then terminate the `racoon` process that's running:

```
sudo racoonctl vpn-disconnect

sudo killall racoon
```

Then, re-load the `launchd` config for `racoon`:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.racoon.plist
```

**How to make this configuration permanent**

If the `racoon` configuration file that you used in the tests above seems to be allowing phase 1 to complete, you can configure `racoon` to use that config file in the future:

Copy the config file that is on your Desktop into the folder /etc/racoon:

```
sudo cp ~/Desktop/vpn.aec.com.br.conf /etc/racoon/vpn.aec.com.br.conf
```

Make sure to secure the permissions on that file:

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/racoon/vpn.aec.com.br.conf
```

Comment out the last line of the file at `/etc/racoon/racoon.conf`, and add a line that will load the configuration that you copied to `/etc/racoon` in the step above:

```
include "/var/run/racoon/*.conf" ;
```

Should be changed to:

```
#include "/var/run/racoon/*.conf" ;
include "/etc/racoon/vpn.aec.com.br.conf" ;
```

After you've made this change, you can save the file and attempt the VPN connection again from the menu bar.

Comment: well... "Oct 15 22:25:18 Leonardo-Ferreiras-iMac.local racoon[27389]: IPSec Phase1 established (Initiated by me)."... is that a good thing?

Comment: It seems to be...This indicates that your machine should be using main mode when connecting to the VPN (or at least you're getting further than you were with aggressive mode). As far as how to enable main mode in the configuration - it should be generating a config file with that information...I"m assuming that the file you copied from `/var/run/racoon` had aggressive mode set? Is the L2TP/IPSec VPN interface that you have created in System Preferences one that was carried over from an old machine? It might help to remove and re-add that VPN interface or create a new network location?

Comment: yes, aggressive mode was set. I already re-created the VPN from scratch a couple of times... every-time aggressive mode comes back on... when using the command line: How can i know that the VPN is up? will i get a "connected" or something?

Comment: i add the ",base" to the exchange and i got a "VPN connexion established" but i dont think that it means what i think it means... or maybe some config is missing... because, for example, i cant ping my machine based on its name...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "i add the ",base" to the exchange"? Note: the steps using `racoon` above are only for troubleshooting the phase 1 connection. You should undo the setup as described at the end of the article to restore the normal function of `racoon`. Once you've restored the configuration, it will still be necessary to figure out how to get OS X to create the correct configuration files. It's possible that removing the file at `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist` may help, but I have not confirmed where that configuration is being generated from.

Comment: in the racoon config file, i set the exchange_mode to "main,base"... after all that just got mt passed phase 1... in phase 2 the connection fails logging: "notification message 18:INVALID-ID-INFORMATION, doi=1 proto_id=3 spi=0c133028(size=4)." in the "racoon.log" file

Comment: I've added information on how to configure the modified .conf file to be used permanently.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that **Back to My Mac** is *disabled* under **System Preferences** → **iCloud**.
2. There are certain characters that OS X does not like in shared secrets. Make sure that your shared secret…

   - is shorter than 64 characters in length
   - does not contain `'` (apostrophe)
   - does not contain `′`, `″` or `‴` (prime, double prime or triple prime)
3. Allow access to your key stored in Keychain Access:

   1. Open **Keychain Access** (`/Applications/Utilities/`)
   2. Select the **System** keychain on the top-left list of keychains.

      [image]
   3. Find the certificate relating to your VPN server and click the disclosure triangle to the left of it to show the **Private Key** (should have a key icon).

      [image]
   4. Double-click it to open the Private Key properties, and select the **Access Control** tab.
   5. Select **Allow all applications to access this item**.
   6. Click **Save Changes** and enter your administrator password.

Comment: no luck... "Back to My Mac" was activated, but clearing it did not solved it... the secret does contains specials chars but they are '*','$' and '+'... the logs remain the same...

Comment: well, there are no certificates that match my vpn... all I have is "IPSec Shared Secret"... no certificates... anyway, I allowed every one to access it but it did not get me through... logs remain the same